# Calling MVC view from jQuery Datepicker()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

How do I call/refresh a view from a jQuery Datepicker() setup in a layout view?

I have a Datepicker setup in my layout view as follows:

```
<header>
        <div class="float-left" id="CalenderView">
            <span class="datepicker">Date:
                <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="10"></span>
        </div>
</header>
```

Script in footer ....

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
                onSelect: function () {
                    var date = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                       data: { "date": date },
                        url: '/Home/Calender',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (response) {},
                        error: function (data) { }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

In my HomeController ...

```
    public ActionResult Calender(String date)
    {
        var rev = new DashboardRevenue();
        rev.PPMRevenue = 1500;
        rev.ProductRev = 1000;
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return View("Dashboard",rev);
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

The return View statement in the controller is ignored. The original view is always rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` looks at the "X-Requested-With" header and checks to see if the value is "XMLHttpRequest".

```
request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"
```

If it is not going into this if-statement, then the header value is most likely not being included. Using the developer tools in your browser or Fiddler, check what headers are being passed in.

Source for [IsAjaxRequest](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/AjaxRequestExtensions.cs).

Comment: If I set a break on return View("Dashboard", rev); in the controller, it hits it. So the Request.IsAjaxRequest() is working. The return View(...) however, has no effect on what is displayed.

Comment: In the `success` portion of your ajax callback, you are not doing anything with the `response`. You should have something like: `function (response) { $('#myDashboard').html(response); }`

Comment: Thanks. But really I want to render the view in the controller with the view using the updated model. I just don't see how to do that in the function (response) {...}, I tried success: function (response) { $('/Home/Calendar').html(response); }. Maybe I should look at a different approach altogether.

Comment: Your approach is correct. The action method would render the view and return it. In my example `$('#myDashboard')`, I am setting the HTML of a div with ID of myDashboard. In your example, you are using `$('/Home/Calendar')`, which is not correct. You'll need to use jQuery to find the element that is on your page where you want to place the returned HTML. `/Home/Calendar` is not correct.

Comment: But I don't have a div to direct to - I have a MVC view I want to render - a different page altogether from where the datepicker is (the layout view). Thanks again for your replies.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize you wanted to wanted to redirect. In that case, you don't need to do an ajax call.